# elasticsearch query with ext attribute

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I made a request using Jest and QueryBuilders, but when I do my tests unitarists the executed query is:

```
"Query": {
    "Match_all": {
    "Boost": 1.0
   }
}
```

But when I go up the application and perform using the Jest and exeucuto one ext attribute is attached to it and ocorreo the following error:

```
"Query": {
    "Match_all": {
    "Boost": 1.0
   }
}
"Ext": {}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchExtBuilder.java

> Intermediate serializable representation of a search ext section. To
>   be subclassed by plugins that support a custom section as part of a
>   search request, which will be provided within the ext element. Any
>   state needs to be serialized as part of the {@link
>   Writeable#writeTo(StreamOutput)} method and read from the incoming
>   stream, usually done adding a constructor that takes {@link
>   StreamInput} as an argument.
>
> Registration happens through {@link SearchPlugin#getSearchExts()},
>   which also needs a {@link NoContextParser} that's able to parse the
>   incoming request from the REST layer into the proper {@link
>   SearchExtBuilder} subclass.
>
> {@link #getWriteableName()} must return the same name as the one used
>   for the registration of the {@link SearchExtSpec}.
>
> @see SearchExtSpec